# Knockout 3.5.0 arrayChange

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I have been facing some issues regarding "foreach" binding to an ko.observableArray for knockout, specifically knockout 3.5.0. The "foreach" binding is creating 2 elements on the U.I side while in the current data context, i am only having one single object within an observableArray. i am binding it as follows:

```
<!-- ko foreach: { data: $root.(...my own javascript function)') } -->
...
<!-- /ko -->
```

What i am doing here is that i am manually adding a new entry into an empty observableArray by calling .push() on the observableArray. The entry is added successfully to the observableArray, however it will show 2 UI elements instead of one even though I am only pushing in one entry into the observableArray.

However, if i set the attribute "includeDestroyed: false", it seems that the problem will disappear.

From what i have gathered, there were a few changes in Knockout 3.5.0 that relates to the implementation of foreach binding being changed in knockout. There has been a change to the implementation of "arrayChange" which detects any changes in the knockout observable array.

What I would like to know is the exact flow of what goes on during an "arrayChange" event, and is there any way i can find out how an empty observableArray handles a "push" function

Answer (score 0):

From the official Knockout github page, when looking into release changelogs you can spot the following:

> To improve performance when array changes are from a known, single 
>   operation, such as push, the foreach binding no longer filters out 
>   destroyed items by default. To turn this off and filter out destroyed 
>   items, you can set includeDestroyed: false in the foreach binding or 
>   set ko.options.foreachHidesDestroyed = true to use the previous
>   behavior by default.

So you can either set the "ko.options" globbaly, or set the flag like you do.

For more info you can look [here](https://github.com/knockout/knockout/releases). 
As for the flow of the event, i suggest looking into the debug version of ko 3.5, along with a debugger and coffe!